# Slick slider positioning and width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to CSS and trying to use Slick slider on a project: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

I have a `div container` which occupies 100% of the pages width.. I then have a div inside that (that contains the slider) which occupies 80% of the width.

However, i am trying to get the div to be positioned in the center of the page and also i am unable to see the left button.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="grid-wrap">
      <div class="grid-col one-eighth">
        <div class="your-class">
          <div>test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1 test1</div>
          <div>test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2</div>
          <div>test3 test3 test3 test3 test3 test3 test3 test3 test3 test3 test3 test3 test3 test3 test3 test3 test3 test3</div>
          <div>test4 test4 test4 test4 test4 test4 test4 test4 test4 test4 test4 test4 test4 test4 test4 test4 test4 test4 test4 test4</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  /* margin-left: 40px; */
}
.clearfix: before, .clearfix: after, .container: before, .container: after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.clearfix: after, .container: after {
  clear: both;
}
.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.grid-wrap {
  margin-left: -3em;
  /* the same as your gutter */
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
}
.grid-col {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 3em;
  /* this is your gutter between columns */
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0 0 150px;
}   
.one-eighth {
  width: 80%;
}
```

Here's a plunker demo'ing the problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/q7eN9wYbbSjq13reLDdD?p=preview

Really struggling with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this css

```
   .grid-wrap { 
      clear: both;
    }

.container {

  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

you can also use this if `.container` will have some more elements

```
.grid-wrap {
  /* margin-left: -3em; */
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  clear: both;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**update** remove `padding-left: 3em;`

```
.grid-col {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: so remove the overflow and margin-left?

Comment: thanks, i tried that originally, but the slider still doesnt still in the centre of the screen. Also, if i remove the -3em, the left button does not have the same spacing from the text as the right button.. Have a look at the plunker.

Comment: can you provide a plunker?

Comment: increase width according to need.

Comment: thanks, but try increasing the width of one-eighth to 100%.. You'll see the slider doesnt sit in the middle of the page and the left button doesnt have the same spacing as the right. See here a fork: http://plnkr.co/edit/z1FuAh6i8NBC601WYWKm?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

remove this line

```
 margin-left: -3em;
```

in your `.grid-wrap` class

```
.grid-wrap {
  margin-left: -3em; //remove this line
  /* the same as your gutter */
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
}
```

add this css

```
.your-class {
   padding-left: 2em; 
}
```

**[SEE DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/urX4EyPE4QLe4UnK7nJa?p=preview)**

Comment: @DyrandzFamadr - thanks, i tried that originally, but the slider still doesnt still in the centre of the screen. Also, if i remove the -3em, the left button does not have the same spacing from the text as the right button.